# check formula ( Functions math ) use Pattern in java ?

Tags: java, string, math, pattern-matching

i need to check formula math  if correct or not  in java use Pattern
formula don't have  {+,-,/,*,=} ,it  have only number or variable or function 
formula like this 
exemple:

1) x1 :=>  true   or  x :=> true

2) 14 :=> true or 1.2 :=>true

3) f(x) :=> true

4)  f(x,4,g(y)) :=> true

5)  f(x :=>  false

7) 7x :=> false

8) x , y :=> false

sorry for my bad english

Comment: What is "Pattern formula"?

Comment: parse string character by character and check whether it is equal to "should not use character"

Comment: nothing i have tried to do something but nothing

Comment: formula is  math function

Comment: but it have only number or variable or  function  and also function can have  number and variable and function  like  this formula f(x,4,g(y))

Answer (score 2):

To use the Pattern class you need to make a regular expression as input to the Pattern.  Start simply and build it up.  Here is a simple one to start with `"[a-z]"`  It will only match plain "variable names" like "x" or "b".  A great online regex research site is https://regex101.com/